# jQuery Supersized Not Stretching Vertically

Tags: jquery, css, supersized

I have a 1920x1200 background image which is resized with jQuery Supersized. It is not resizing properly vertically; as I resize the browser, a gap appears as soon as the width is constrained (and it must fill vertically to compensate, but it doesn't).

I copied these settings from another user whose 1920x1200 image resizes perfectly. What am I missing?

First of all, the CSS: note the height/width are 100%:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#supersized a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -30;
}

#supersized a.activeslide {
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Inserted JS:

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/supersized.core.3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function($){

                $.supersized({

                        //Functionality
                    slideshow : 0, //Slideshow on/off
                    autoplay : 1, //Slideshow starts playing automatically
                    start_slide : 1, //Start slide (0 is random)
                    random : 0, //Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                    slide_interval : 6000, //Length between transitions
                    transition : 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                    transition_speed : 500, //Speed of transition
                    new_window : 1, //Image links open in new window/tab
                    pause_hover : 0, //Pause slideshow on hover
                    keyboard_nav : 0, //Keyboard navigation on/off
                    performance : 1, //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                    image_protect : 1, //Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript
                    image_path : 'img/', //Default image path
                    //Size & Position
                    min_width : 0, //Min width allowed (in pixels)
                    min_height : 0, //Min height allowed (in pixels)
                    vertical_center : 1, //Vertically center background
                    horizontal_center : 1, //Horizontally center background
                    fit_portrait : 1, //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                    fit_landscape : 0, //Landscape images will not exceed browser width
                    //Components
                    navigation : 0, //Slideshow controls on/off
                    thumbnail_navigation : 0, //Thumbnail navigation
                    slide_counter : 0, //Display slide numbers
                    slide_captions : 0, //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)                 

                    slides  :   [ {image : 'example.com/image.png', title : 'Test'} ]
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle please

Comment: Thank you, the Fiddle worked, here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/f7jvnqms/1/
It helped me fix the issue. The problem was it was not finding the Supersized CSS. When I pasted that CSS into the main CSS, it started working.
Here's my other question: Is there a way to keep the image anchored at Left/Top? Right now, Supersized always centers it.

Comment: i'll take a look now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation and your new question, here's a working fiddle without centering.  http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/35qc7yht/

You need to modify the following code:

```
horizontal_center: 0, // left align background
```

Also please see my updated fiddle to see how to properly do one.  All javascript goes in the javascript section, you don't need the html and body tags, you add jquery using the menu on the left, and you add external resources (like the supersized library also with the menu on the left.